# Issues with Runtime Error '2185' while using combo box to search dynamically on continuous form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am having an issue while trying to search in a combo box that dynamically filters a continuous form. The code is as follows:

```
Private Sub cboFormFilter_Change()

    If Nz(Me.cboFormFilter.Text) = "" Then
        Me.Form.Filter = ""
        Me.FilterOn = False

        ElseIf Me.cboFormFilter.ListIndex <> -1 Then
           Me.Form.Filter = "[Description] = '" & _
              Replace(Me.cboFormFilter.Text, "'", """") & "'"
           Me.FilterOn = True

        Else
           Me.Form.Filter = "[Description] Like '*" & _
              Replace(Me.cboFormFilter.Text, "'", """") & "*'"
           Me.FilterOn = True

    End If

    Me.cboFormFilter.SetFocus
    Me.cboFormFilter.SelStart = Len(Me.cboFormFilter.Text)

End Sub
```

This code works excellent, but the second I type something that isn't on the continuous form, it will give me the runtime error "2185'

for example, if my continuous form only has records called 'Hello World' and I type in Hello Worlds, it will pop up the error.

I've searched around the internet to find out what is going on, but couldn't figure it out. Other people were having issues similar to the one I am having and they said to remove the .Text, but this still results in the 2185 error. I'm out of ideas and my brain is melted. Any ideas?

Comment: In theory, I'd like it to return a message notifying the user that there's no records, or even allow the user to keep typing even though there's no records to be found. However, it instead give me the error 2185.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling 'runtime error 2185' yields results about an error that occurs when you're trying to access a control's properties without the control having focus (would have been nice to include the error message in your question).

It seems weird that the control wouldn't be having focus, since it's *that control* raising the `Change` event you're handling here.

So I'd just wrap the code in an error handler and work it from there:

```
On Error GoTo CleanFail

    'your code

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    If Err.Number = 2158 Then
        'handle the error - msgbox, whatever
        Err.Clear
        Resume CleanExit
    End If
```

Comment: .text is NOT the default property. the default property is .value. Both .value and .text can be examined independent of each other, however the .text property is ONLY available when the control has the focus. As "general" approach we always use .value and thus the focus does not matter. However the "control" .value is NOT updated until the control focus changes. So for most combo box code, it should be placed in the after update event, and the default .value property can and SHOULD be used. The only "real" use of .text is in the on-change event to examine the current  contents of the control.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Good to know; I admitedly made an assumption here. Edited that part out for correctness. Thanks!